# After successful build application does not work codename one

Tags: codenameone

I build a simple application of showing a chart. Locally,running application on simulator, it was working fine. I send a android build on codename one build server, build was successful.

I downloaded the apk file and installed on my Nexus 5 (Android Lollipop) and it just throw me this error

```
An internal application error occurred :
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : Failed resolution of :
Lorg/achartengine/compat/Context;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you used the cn1lib for achartengine, did you do something with it?

Comment: yes, i extracted the cn1lib and copied all class files to my lib/impl/cls and java files to lib/impl/stubs . But you answered my first question , this time i am doing it right way by clicking Refresh Libs so i guess it wont bother me any more. Thanks  man for the help.